# Spring MVC - Update entity in controller with PUT

Tags: spring-mvc, request, http-put, request-mapping, path-variables

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Price pricePerDay;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    @OneToOne
    private Room room;
    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;



@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    @OneToOne
    private CustomerAddress customerAddress;
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

@Entity
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int roomNumber;
    private RoomType roomType;
    private BedType bedType;
    private int bedNumber = 1;
    private boolean oceanView = false;
    private boolean airConditioning = false;
    private boolean balcony = false;
    @OneToOne
    private Price pricePerNight;
```

I have Repository and Service with `update(Booking booking)` which updates a booking based on a given id.(Let's assume that code is ok)

Please help me construct the Controller for Updating a Room in a Booking by calling a booking by id with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bookings/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

If additional info are needed I will provide them.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is a sample controller method.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/booking/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String list(@PathVariable String id){
     Booking booking= bookingRepository.findOne(id);

    //code

      bookingService.update(booking);
}
```

`RequestMethod.PUT` indicates we are updating an existing booking so we need not give the `update` in the path.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this and I get an error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"

Comment: Exactly when /booking/{id} is called with with PUT, with GET I can see the the booking details, no problems ther. If you need to see the code please tell me.

Comment: this works ok: `@RequestMapping(value = "/bookings/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        Booking booking = bookingService.searchById(id);

        return new ModelAndView("updatebooking", "booking", booking);
    }`

Comment: this doesn't work, it never enters this method: `@RequestMapping(value = "/bookings/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String updateBooking(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Booking booking) {
        Booking updatedBooking = new Booking();
        updatedBooking.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
/code/
bookingService.update(updatedBooking);

        return "updatebooking";
    }`

Comment: The issue here is because you have Id as int and when you search using repository you pass the string and hence the error.

Comment: It's not that; it finds the room,  it returns the room data. At least it's not when bookingService.searchById(id) is called. Anyway I still don't know how to fix it. If you can help me further I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution, if I use RequestMethod.POST instead of PUT, it is working fine. I am using Thymeleaf template and it seems that PUT method doesn't work, only POST. Thanks for help.